# Is there a way to implement chart-js-plugin-waterfall as a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2, waterfall

I'm facing a situation here, including React use coupled with the additionnal plugin from the chart.js library : chartjs-plugin-waterfall.

I have to develop a personalised dashboard for my client, and until now I've been able to implement every type of charts needed with the library chartjs and its react components : react-chartjs-2.

But I'm now struggling for hours with the last one I have to implement -and which is not available as a "react-chart component"- : the Waterfall chart.
For this I decided to add chartjs-plugin-waterfall and to implement it as a new Chart (here a code sample) :

```
const WaterFallType = () => {
    let chart = false
    useEffect(() => {
        if(chart instanceof Chart) {
            chart.destroy();
        }
        let ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d')

        chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: "bar",
            plugins: [waterFallPlugin],
            data :{
                datasets: [
                  {
                    label: 'Closing Costs',
                    data: [50],
                    backgroundColor: '#e8cdd7',
                    stack: 'stack 1',
                  },
                  {
                    label: 'Purchase Price',
                    data: [700],
                    backgroundColor: '#d29baf',
                    stack: 'stack 1',
                  },
                  {
                    data: [200],
                    waterfall: {
                      dummyStack: true,
                    },
                    stack: 'stack 2',
                  },
                  {
                    label: 'Opening Loan Balance',
                    data: [550],
                    backgroundColor: '#bb6987',
                    stack: 'stack 2',
                  },
                  {
                    label: 'Initial Cash Investment',
                    data: [200],
                    backgroundColor: '#a53860',
                    stack: 'stack 3',
                  },
                ],
            },
            options: {
                plugins: {
                  waterFallPlugin: {
                    stepLines: {
                      enabled: true,
                      startColorStop: 0,
                      endColorStop: 0.6,
                      startColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55)',
                      endColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                      diagonalStepLines: true,
                    },
                  },
                },
            }
              
        })
    }, [chart])

    return <div>
        <canvas id="myChart" width="400px" height="400px"></canvas>
    </div>
}
export default WaterFallType
```

Unfortunatly This code does not render the component, instead it throws me several errors :

First one : "Uncaught Error: Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '2' must be destroyed before the canvas can be reused."

Second one : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'filter')"

Could anyone help me with this battle?
Thank you very much for your help.

Benjamin

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution without any plugin need.
Chart.js allows floating bars :
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.2.1/samples/bar/floating.html

Which makes it a lot more easier!

Have an excellent day!